# Get email notifications for pr's and issues on my github repo

Tags: github, github-issues

How can I get email notifications when somebody opens an issue on a repository I own ? 
I have a small open source plugin I manage, and when a user reports an issue, or send a PR, it's important for me to be notified of it.

I can't seem to find any setting that will allow me to setup an email for my repo.
I am able to configure email notifications for existing issues, but this is not what I need.

Answer (score 2):

You can [subscribe to to a repository using the Watch option](https://help.github.com/en/articles/watching-and-unwatching-repositories#watching-a-single-repository). There is a "Watch" button near the top right next to Star and Fork of each repository's home page.

> You can watch a repository to receive notifications for new pull requests and issues that are created. You can also unwatch a repository if you no longer want to receive notifications for that specific repository.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I had disabled notifications in https://github.com/settings/notifications. 
Enabling "email" and "web" under Watching solved the issue.